# How to combine more than two filters in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to write query like this for elasticsearch 1.7:

```
SELECT * FROM prods WHERE 
id=1 AND 
name='flower' AND 
(count_usd=1 OR prise_usd=5) AND 
(count_eur=1 OR prise_eur=5)
```

?
I've read about nested bool ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/combining-filters.html ) but cannot apply it to my context :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest a `bool` query within a `bool` query to achieve this kind of filtering:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {"name":"flower"}
                    }],
                    "should": [{
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "count_usd": 1
                                }
                            }, {
                                "term": {
                                    "prise_usd": 5
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "count_eur": 1
                                }
                            }, {
                                "term": {
                                    "prise_eur": 5
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `should` clause acts like an `OR`: at least one of the subclauses in a `should` must be true to match.

Comment: Thank you! That's great!

Comment: I think the first `should` should be a `must` if you want to achieve the AND between the ORs